A quase a dois meses o comentário automático para sinalização de possível pergunta duplicada está sem tradução
Em pergunta criada 12/09/2024 passado, eu a sinalizei como possível pergunta
duplicada e o comentário automático emitido foi:

This question is similar to: O que é "nível de granularidade" e como identificá-lo?. If
you believe it’s different, please
editar the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the
answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hoje dia 30/10/2024 sinalizei uma pergunta como possível pergunta
duplicada e o comentário automático emitido foi:

This question is similar to: Qual codificação de caracteres
(Collation) devo usar em Mysql?. If you believe it’s different, please
editar the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the
answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ambos o comentário feitos em língua inglesa em site localizado ao público falante de lingua portuguesa.
Desde que o Traducir foi migrado para estrutura interna da SE a comunidade perdeu a capacidade de corrigir os problemas de localização do site.
Então por meio dessa publicação venho a informar a SE problema e solicitar seu reparo.

Enviei a tradução, depois precisamos testar se funciona (recebe tag que o problema da pergunta não é 'reprodutível' no sentido de ser possível correção pela comunidade) ou se permanece errado (recebe tag de que o problema requer atenção do staff)
